# Showing algebra is division algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebras

> Suppose $A$ is a $k$-subalgebra of $M_n(k)$ containing the identity of $M_n(k)$, where $k$ is a field. Suppose $A$ is a domain. I would like to show that $A$ is a division algebra and $\dim_k(A) \mid n$.

Since $A$ is a $k$-subalgebra of $M_n(k)$, $A$ is Artinian and the Jacobson radical $J(A)$ is nilpotent. Since $A$ is a domain, $A$ is Jacobson semisimple and $J(A)=0$. So $A$ Artinian and Jacobson semisimple implies $A$ is semisimple.

 By Artin-Wedderburn, $A \cong M_{n_1}(D_1) \oplus \cdots\oplus M_{n_r}(D_r)$, where the $D_i$ are division rings. Since $A$ is a domain, we must have each $n_i=1$ and each $D_i$ a domain, so $A$ is a division algebra.

 How do I show that $\dim_k(A) \mid n$?

 Also, if $A$ is simple, how can I show that $\dim_k(A) \mid n^2$?

Comment: Note that if there are two direct summands, then $A$ is *not* a domain!

Comment: If $A$ is a division algebra, it's a skew-field, so $M_n(k)$ is a (say left) module over $A$, so $M_n(k)$ must be a free $A$-module of some rank $r$. It follows that $\dim_k M_n(k) = r \dim_k A$, so $n^2 = r \dim_k A$, so $\dim_k A \mid n^2$. Note that a division algebra is automatically simple. I do not know what you meant to write at the end.

Comment: You can also  make the observation that a finite dimensional algebra without zero divisors is always a division algebra.